# SQL Server Transpose for single record

Tags: sql-server

I have below table with a single record in it.

```
|OPC|IPC|CC|
|223|426|17|
```

I want output something like this:

```
|TypeC|Value|
|OPC  |223  |
|IPC  |426  |
|CC   |17   |
```

with minimum logic & in optimized way.

Please find the below create/insert table

```
CREATE TABLE HELLO_REPORT(OPC INT,IPC INT,CC INT)
INSERT INTO HELLO_REPORT SELECT 23,46,17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UNPIVOT:

```
SELECT  TypeC,Value
FROM    HELLO_REPORT
UNPIVOT
(
    Value FOR TypeC IN (OPC,IPC,CC)
) unpvt
```

Comment: I was using the pivot. Thank you.

Comment: please mark as answer if it was helpful - thank you!